# Reading in Date / Time Values Correctly

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Any ideas on how I can manipulate my current date-time data to make it suitable for use when converting the datatype to time?
For example:

```
df1['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date/Time'])
```

The current format for the data is mm/dd 00:00:00

an example of the column in the dataframe can be seen below.

```
          Date/Time  Dry_Temp[C]  Wet_Temp[C]  Solar_Diffuse_Rate[[W/m2]]  \
0   01/01  00:10:00         8.45     8.237306                         0.0   
1   01/01  00:20:00         7.30     6.968360                         0.0   
2   01/01  00:30:00         6.15     5.710239                         0.0   
3   01/01  00:40:00         5.00     4.462898                         0.0   
4   01/01  00:50:00         3.85     3.226244                         0.0
```

Comment: ```df1['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date/Time'], format='%m:5d %H:%M:%S')``` will give you the month and day with the year being the start of the epoch.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This didnt work for me, I believe you meant a % instead of 5 which i tried but no luck

Comment: yes you are correct,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the condition where the hour is denoted as 24, you have two choices.  First you can simply reset the hour to 00 and second you can reset the hour to 00 and also add 1 to the date.
In either case the first step is detecting the condition which can be done with a simple find statement `t.find('  24:')`
Having detected the condition in the first case it is a simple matter of reseting the hour to 00 and proceeding with the process of formatting the field.  In the second case, however, adding 1 to the day is a little more complicated because of the fact you can roll over to next month.

Here is the approach I would use:

Given a df of form:

```
    Date Time
0   01/01 00:00:00
1   01/01 00:24:00
2   01/01 24:00:00
3   01/31 24:00:00
```

The First Case

```
def parseDate2(tx):
    ti = tx.find('  24:')
    if ti >= 0:
        tk = pd.to_datetime(tx[:5]+'  00:'+tx[10:], format= '%m/%d  %H:%M:%S') 
        return tk + du.relativedelta.relativedelta(hours=+24)
    return pd.to_datetime(tx, format= '%m/%d  %H:%M:%S')        

df['Date Time'] = df['Date Time'].apply(lambda x: parseDate(x))
```

Produces the following:

```
    Date Time
0   1900-01-01 00:00:00
1   1900-01-01 00:24:00
2   1900-01-01 00:00:00
3   1900-01-31 00:00:00
```

For the second case, I employed the dateutil relativedelta library and slightly modified my parseDate funstion as shown below:

```
import dateutil as du
def parseDate2(tx):
    ti = tx.find('  24:')
    if ti >= 0:
        tk = pd.to_datetime(tx[:5]+'  00:'+tx[10:], format= '%m/%d  %H:%M:%S') 
        return tk + du.relativedelta.relativedelta(hours=+24)
    return pd.to_datetime(tx, format= '%m/%d  %H:%M:%S')        

df['Date Time'] = df['Date Time'].apply(lambda x: parseDate2(x))
```

Yields:

```
    Date Time
0   1900-01-01 00:00:00
1   1900-01-01 00:24:00
2   1900-01-02 00:00:00
3   1900-02-01 00:00:00

​
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the values of the datetime (namely the time), you can use:

```
# These are now in a usable format
seconds = df1['Date/Time'].dt.second
minutes = df1['Date/Time'].dt.minute
hours = df1['Date/Time'].dt.hours
```

And if need be, you can create its own independent time series with:

```
df1['Dat/Time'].dt.time
```

Comment: Hi, it seems this does not work for me :(

Comment: As @itproh66 inferred, which I didn't realise at the time (and am still unsure now): is your input a string? If so, you can pass it through using the formatting he gave, and manipulate the data using the variables I mentioned above. Some extra code examples would be helpful, especially an ideal before / after (desired result).

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, which is that in my date/time column, I have some values which read 24:00:00, Which is not supported by the DateTime Libraries, do you have any ideas on how I can edit all 24:00:00 cells such that they read 00:00:00?

Comment: yes the current format is string

Comment: which do you want to do if the hour =n 24?  reset to 00 or increase day by 1 and reset hour to 00?

Comment: What you can do simply is iterate through and replace "24:00:00" with "00:00:00" because you unable to convert it to datetime in the first place which means you can't edit it functionally, only replacement-wise. - And, as @itproh66 mentioned, increase the date by one on all the ones you changed